# Upload image to server via form in Flutter?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, image-uploading, flutter-dependencies

I am creating an app with flutter. I have a form that have some fields like name, before_edit_images, after_edit_images etc. It has dynamic form fields.

I simply want to upload images with rest of form fields when form is saved. Like the image should have reference to which field it has been uploaded from.

I have check simple image uploads, But i need to send form field name against which the images are being uploaded

Any help will be appreciated. Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: did you check if that's possible with multipart request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you just need to turn the image into a base64 String, and then you can use it as any other form field.